# What is the wedge product of two vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

I've seen the notion of a wedge product for differential forms, but I've recently come across the notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\wedge\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$, where these are vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Apparently, this is supposed to be an object that takes two smooth functions and produces a smooth function. How exactly does this act though?

Comment: I've never in my life thought of it this way. I think it as a $2$-vector (so you visualize an oriented parallelogram spanned by the two vectors). But you can, I suppose, take $(X\otimes Y)(f,g) = X(f)Y(g)$ and then $X\wedge Y = X\otimes Y - Y\otimes X$, so $(X\wedge Y)(f,g) = X(f)Y(g)-X(g)Y(f)$.

Comment: That's a natural way to think about it in geometry i.e. an element $X\in T_{p}M$ (the tangent space to a manifold $M$ at point $p$) is a 'derivation' acting on smooth functions in a neighbourhood of $p$. Above, you've just set $M=\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Check out Lee's book on manifolds.